# Is it possible to pass a function as argument to other function in ColdFusion? If yes how?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I am trying to find a way to pass a function as argument to other function like this:

```
<cfset function_A(function_B())/>
```

Here function_A and function_B are user defined functions.

Comment: It is possible, but, why would you want to? Is function_b is a UDF, you can simply call it from within function_A.

Comment: This link will answer your question.  http://www.silverink.nl/passing-functions-arguments/

Comment: @DanBracuk  Looking at the link you provided, the code sample given shows functions defined that are callable only within the scope of another function.  Even though the title of the page is called **Passing Functions as Arguments**, that's not what's really going on in that article.

Comment: `<cfset function_A(function_B())/>` is passing the `result` of B to A. Are you asking to pass function B into A as an `argument`, so that you then you execute B within the scope of A? If so, then what @ScottStroz says.

Answer (score 2):

We do this all the time.

```
<cffunction  name="myfucn1">
    <cfreturn 100>
</cffunction>

<cffunction  name="myfunc2">
    <cfargument  name="myNum">
    <cfdump  var="#arguments.myNUm#">
    <cfabort>
</cffunction>

<cfset myfunc2(myfucn1())>
```

The output you will get is 100

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can pass a function as an argument.  This is no different than any other language.  As long as the return type of `function_B()` is the same data type as the first argument of `function_A()` then your example of `<cfset function_A(function_B())/>` is completely valid.

What you're asking is a common practice and done all the time.  For example, you need to get the maximum number from 3 different values.  You would accomplish it like this.

```
<cfset maxVal = max(a, max(b, c))>
```

As you can see, `max()` accepts 2 arguments.  Presuming a, b, and c are all valid numbers, the first argument is numeric and the second argument is a function that returns the greater numeric value of b and c.
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/max.html